# how to find MCA User id for IBM websphere MQ 7

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I created a QM and Queue using the User Guide MQ-7.1. Now i want send message from a Java application so i followed the guide and created a channel but i dont know whether only Server-connection Channel should be created or anything else more to be done. When I try to access it I get an Exception.

```
MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2035
MQJE036: Queue manager rejected connection attempt”.
```

I got a link(http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1490) where it tells to add MCA User ID. But i dont know how to find it. I will be very happy if any one of you help me on this

--Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need only the Server Connection channel and the MCA user can be set using the MQ Explorer or the command line (runmqsc).

Here is the link to runmqsc: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc%2Ffa11160_.htm

Here is the link to the ALTER command that can be used to change the MCA user on the channel : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaj.doc/sc10480_.htm

Comment: After this, you need to give authorizations/permissions to put messages to the queue. You can use setmqaut or the new AUTHREC commands from MQSC console (runmqsc) or the explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (for was mq 7.0)

add Server connection channel:

(in Linux)    `DEFINE CHANNEL(CHNAME) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) MCAUSER('mqm') ;`

(in windows)  `DEFINE CHANNEL(CHNAME) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) MCAUSER('MUSR_MQADMIN') ;`